# How to send localdb database with other guys

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, localdb

I am working on some project with 2 other friends. Project is website in angular and asp.net and sqllocaldb for database. We want to access at the same database and read same data from database.
How can we do it?

I changed some option in Microsoft SQL Server Menagement Studio. Set TCP to enable and port to 1433. I saw that in tutorial but it didnt work

Comment: If you want to access the *same* database localdb is the wrong choice as, as the name suggests, it's *local*, so each individual has their own instance of it. You'll need SQL Server as a Service.

Comment: If you want to share a database, you need to host it on a server that you all have access to. Since it sounds like you don't have much experience with that sort of thing, it might be best to use a hosted, managed instance such as [Azure SQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/azure-sql/database/). Could be as cheap as $5 USD/month, which may be covered by free trial and/or student credits.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.